# Dynamic update with PHP and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Below is my Javascript script that should go through the array of selected nodes (from the checkbox tree) and go one by one and get info with snmpget or snmpwalk (php script) and update the meter in the client.

First I try in each iteration in loop to run three diff snmp php script (snmpget * 3) scripts .. now I make it more efficient by doing now in each iteration I run one php script that relay on snmpwalk - but the result are the same.

arrNodes = array of selected nodes in the tree
g1_0 , g2_0 , g3_0 are the gouges for each selected node in the tree ( 0 is the index )

```
  window.onload = function()
  {                                 
     setInterval(function() {   



                function ajaxwalk(i,ip,os,snmpcomm) {
                     $.get("ajax/PrefWalk.php",{Uip:ip,Uos:os,Ucom:snmpcomm}, function(value) {

                      var data = value.split(",");
                       //console.log(data);
                       window["g1_"+i].refresh(data[1]);
                       window["g2_"+i].refresh(data[0]);
                       window["g3_"+i].refresh(data[2]);
                     });                   
                }                  


             for (var i = 0 ; i < arrNodes.length ; i++ )                                     
                  {       
                    var path0=document.getElementById("g1_"+i);
                    var ip=path0.getAttribute('data-ip');

                    var path1=document.getElementById("g1_"+i);
                    var snmpcomm=path1.getAttribute('data-snmpcomunity');

                    var path2=document.getElementById("g1_"+i);
                    var os=path2.getAttribute('data-os');

                      // ajaxCpu(i,ip,os,snmpcomm)                   
                      // ajaxMem(i,ip,os,snmpcomm) 
                        ajaxwalk(i,ip,os,snmpcomm) 

                      //var data = value.split(",");
                       //console.log(data);
                       //window["g1_"+i].refresh(data[1]);
                       //window["g2_"+i].refresh(data[0]);
                       //window["g3_"+i].refresh(data[2]);
                     //});                                            

                  }

    }, 5000);

    }
 );
 </script>
```

anyway , the above code woring great as long as that arrNodes hold one item , when arrNodes hold more then one i have timeoutes ... acually the get req not even seen in the apache access.log ( all but the one that updated ) .
can you guys help here ? what am i doing wrong ?
regards !!!

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Why the function `ajaxwalk` is in the Interval?? it should defined once.

Comment: Miya - in the firebug i can see timeout to the gets ( all but the one i can update ) , no javascript errors                       , Jonnies - i would like to update the gouge every 5 or 10 seconds , that why i put all inside the setinterval